# How to setup a domain on a server?

Tags: apache, ssh, dns, installation, virtualhost

I am running LAMP config on CentOS 5.6

Now, the question is how do I add a domain name to the server? I have already pointed the domain name to the server.

I think the next steps would be something like this.

1. Create a user on centos
2. Create a folder for the domain name within that users directory
3. Create a virtual host on apache pointing the directory to the users directory
4. Add content to the directory of the domain name specified in the virtual host
5. Voila! A new domain name created.

Am I missing something from the list? Also, any other methods to do this or just use ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a user, then you create a domain directory and put your files in there, then you add a virtual domain to apache and restart apache and that should be it.

Obviously dont forget to setup your dns or ask your hosting to set it up for you.

Answer (score 2):

To change domain name, there are a couple config files you need to work with, with root permission. Make sure you backup all original files before making any changes:

1. "/etc/sysconfig/network" which you should replace the default hostname by your FQDN(Fully Qualified Domain Name), something like this: myHostName.myDomainName.
2. "/etc/hosts" which you should add your IP address(es) with corresponding hostname and FQDN, separate by whitespace, something like this: 192.168.1.1 myHostName myHostName.myDomainName
3. "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0" which is a config file for your ethernet interface 0, replace default IP address, network, network mask, gateway, etc. to a proper value. And if your server has more than one interface, you should config all of them. They are in the same directory with the above file I mentioned. Look at the name and you should know which one to amend.

Finally, restart your server.

I recommend [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102488) which I am using as a quick reference. For those steps you mentioned, it depends what you want to achieve. But I suggest you open a new thread for them.